# Heroku foreman appears to start but nothing happens

Tags: python, heroku

I'm working through the Heroku tutorial for deploying a Python app and am trying to [run my app locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#run-the-app-locally) on a Windows 7 64 bit machine. Using foreman to start the app appears work and has no visible errors but doesn't do anything.

Procfile.Windows:

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
```

Foreman output:

```
(HerokuGettingStarted) PS C:\localApp\> foreman start web -f .\Procfile .windows
08:16:04 web.1  | started with pid 6080
08:16:15 web.1  | Performing system checks...
08:16:15 web.1  |
08:16:15 web.1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

If I do a netstat, there's nothing listening on localhost port 5000. However if I start the server manually, it works and I can connect to the app with a browser or telnet.

```
(HerokuGettingStarted) PS C:\localApp\> python manage.py runserver 0.0
.0.0:5000
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 25, 2015 - 08:39:07
Django version 1.8.1, using settings 'gettingstarted.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:5000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. The easiest work-around for this is to just manually run `py manage.py runserver` and you'll be able to run everything locally.

Though the only thing that might not work in the same way is the setting of "config vars", as stated in [**Getting Started with Python on Heroku**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#run-the-app-locally)